# I cant solve my script with cplex or glpk... in python

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I wrote my code in python with pyomo...
at the end, when I want to run my script, I've faced this error:
WARNING: "[base]/site-packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/GLPK.py", 150, _default_executable
    Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is required for solver 'glpk'

ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'glpk'

I work with mac...
And I dont know what should I do to use 'glpk' or 'cplex' to solve my model....

Answer (score 1):

Pyomo is a "pure Python" package and by design does not include any solvers.  You must install all solvers separately.  After installation, make sure that the directory(ies) containing the solver executables (`glpsol`, `cplex`, `gurobi.sh`, etc) are in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Tnx for your answer...
Im new on mac and python!
how can I check the solvers?
I wrote in terminal:
pip install glpk
but I face with error:  Failed building wheel for glpk